# SSIS - MySQL error "Failed to convert parameter value from a DateTime to a Decimal."

Tags: mysql, ssis, integer, timestamp

I have to update table which have column data type as integer, but I have an input as a datetime. this is query that i hve writen

> UPDATE    T_SCH_ETAX_TEMP SET               CURRTIME = UNIX_TIMESTAMP
>   (TIMEDIFF("(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(?,'%H:%i:%s') TIMEONLY)", "(SELECT 
>   DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'%H:%i:%s') TIMEONLY)"),  LENGTHTIME =
>   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMEDIFF("(SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(?,'%H:%i:%s')
>   TIMEONLY)",  "(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'%H:%i:%s')
>   TIMEONLY)")

any one can help how to convert timestamp result as an integer so I can update the table using SSIS

Comment: please list your table structure

Comment: ALTER TABLE `t_sch_etax_temp` CHANGE `DATEMOD` `DATEMOD` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE `CURRTIME` `CURRTIME` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE `LENGTHTIME` `LENGTHTIME` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL;

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, please forgive me if I am, but you *seem* to want something simpler:

```
UPDATE T_SCH_ETAX_TEMP 
SET CURRTIME = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
  TIMEDIFF(TIME(?),
    TIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))), 
LENGTHTIME = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
  TIMEDIFF(TIME(?), TIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)));
```

Which would only require 2 parameters ('ss');

If this is the case, in can be simplified to:

```
UPDATE T_SCH_ETAX_TEMP 
SET CURRTIME = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
  TIMEDIFF(?,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)), 
LENGTHTIME = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
  TIMEDIFF(?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP));
```

if you pre-format your parameter strings

Comment: thank you for answering :)
I have tried this solution, but it can't update the table t_sch_etax_temp

Comment: What language are you using to update? Can we see that code?

Comment: MySQL

UPDATE    T_SCH_ETAX_TEMP
SET              
CURRTIME = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIME_TO_SEC (TIMEDIFF('?', 'SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()'))), 
LENGTHTIME = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIME_TO_SEC (TIMEDIFF('?', 'SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()'))),

Comment: I have been successfully code for this problem. I used timestampdiff function for MySQL. See this article https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff